# Перенаправление htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте.

Нужно перенаправить пользователя с **site.ru/?route=page** на **site.ru/page**

Данное выражение не работает:

```
RewriteRule ^\?route=(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы, наверное, не понимаете механизма работы Rewrite? Когда вы пишите такое, это означает, что при переходе по такому URL, как site.ru/page, фактически Апач передает в приложение такой site.ru/?route=page адрес, а не наоборот. Т.е. никакого редиректа тут нет. Есть только мнимая и действительная часть URL. Для редиректа используйте Redirect [url]. Может, это вам поможет:

```
RewriteRule ^route/(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [NC,L]
#и в консольку sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: @exru, я тоже в этом слаб. Хотел поинтересоваться, есть какая-нибудь интересная статья или книга, описывающая полный функционал команд, какой можно реализовать в htaccess? До сих пор просто изучал чужие htaccess, на этом и строил свои запросы-команды.

Comment: Тут, скорее, нужно изучать регулярные выражения. Сам по себе .htaccess никаких сложностей не представляет. Первые 10 ссылок из гугла достаточно приоткрывают завесу к знаниям. Лично я долго мучался с регулярками, потом просто их выучил раз и навсегда. И потребность в доках .htaccess отпала.